# Count how many times an item appears in a Snapshot in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

As the title says, I need to count how many times a ProductId appears in each Snapshot and I don't seem to figure out how.

Basically, I need to do an update on Table1 so I can populate Column Count as seen below.
Also take in consideration that Table1 has 100,000 different ProductIDs

**Table1 (original)**

```
SnapshotTimeId  ProductID   Count
20170131        15748       NULL
20170228        15748       NULL
20170331        15748       NULL
20170630        578455      NULL
20170731        578455      NULL
20170831        578455      NULL
20170930        578455      NULL
```

**Table1 (after update)**

```
SnapshotTimeId  ProductID   Count
20170131        15748       1
20170228        15748       2
20170331        15748       3
20170630        578455      1
20170731        578455      2
20170831        578455      3
20170930        578455      4
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With regards to your data, what defines a "snapshot"? All the SnapshotTimeIds you provide are unique, with only one (1) ProductID in each.

Comment: The SnapshotTimeId is not unique. It represents the date in INT format eg. 1/11/2018 = 20180111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT SnapshotTimeId, ProductID, Count,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY SnapshotTimeId) NewCount
    FROM yourTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET Count = NewCount;
```

If you don't need to actually update the table, then just do `SELECT *` from the cte.